# For 64 bit windows we need to use 64 bit java

Tags: java, windows-7-x64

Whether  we need to use 64 bit java version for 64 bit windows os (will it work for RSA IDE for Java development)

Comment: You don't need to install everything as 64 bit right? Same goes with the JDK too. For example you might have other softwares too right which aren't 64 bit. Same goes with the JDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its ***not a mandate***.

You ***can*** use 32 bit software of a 64 bit machine. So it is also possible for 32 bit JDK to run on a 64 bit machine. But the inverse is not true.

*Its just that the 32 bit Java will not be able to use 64 bit operations supported. Which means you are **not using full capabilities** of the underlying hardware*

Comment: The point is... if you use a 32 bit s/w on a 64-bit machine, then, you will not be making full use of the capabilities of the 64 bit machine.

Comment: @TheLostMind yes thats what I have pointed out. On a second thought I will remove the image.

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not compulsory. you can use `32-bit JDK` on `64-bit` OS. All depends on your need. Let's say we are doing a new implementation for a currently implemented code based on `32-bit JDK` then you have to continue our code on that environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 32-bit JDK on 64-bit Operating System, but you can't use 64-bit JDK on 32-bit Operating System

Answer (score 0):

```
SUMMARY


 64-bit Windows operating systems (which may be Windows 7, Vista or XP) come with a 32-bit Internet Explorer (IE) browser as the standard (default) for viewing web pages. 
These operating systems also include a 64-bit Internet Explorer browser, however using it is optional and it must be explicitly selected to view web pages. 
Note that because some web content may not work properly in a 64-bit browser, we recommend using the default 32-bit browser and downloading 32-bit Java.
```

Reference:http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml

Hence we can use 32bit Java to 64bit OS as well